# How to print Custom Cell Rendered JTable data in Jasper Report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with my own rendered column.
I need to print table data with jasper report,as showing on swing application.
is there any suggestion to do this with jasper report?
I tried with JRTableModelDataSource,but it is not what I need.
My table is look like this.
[image]

Comment: You need to setup the conditions in the report that can change the context of the cell based on the data that is rendered to it...just like a renderer.  Don't think you can re-use a cell renderer in the report

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-apply-conditional-formatting-your-text-fields)

Comment: First thing is that you have to know about the grouping concept in table and then know about conditional styles. You can also try with cross tables instead of tables.